# Cannot find a link library (lNrrdIO)

Tags: makefile, cmake, symlink

I am trying to install NrrdIO on Ubuntu 18.04, to run Marching Cubes to segment medical images. This is the link from which I'm trying to run it.

http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/research/graphics/isotable/

I'm trying to install ijkmcube-v0-3-3.tar, which requires the ITKNrrdIO.a library. I'm running into this error:

```
[  7%] Linking CXX executable ijkmcube
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNrrdIO
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/build.make:406: recipe for target 'ijkmcube' failed
make[2]: *** [ijkmcube] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:131: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've installed NrrdIO 1.11.0, and tried with NrrdIO 1.9.0 as well, but while  running 
    make
I always run into this error, for some reason its not able to find lNrrdIO . Can someone please help?
Thanks

**Edit:**

I think its a problem with the linking, but when I copied the NrrdIO.a file to /usr/bin and modified the symbolic link to point to it, I got an error as follows:

```
[  7%] Linking CXX executable ijkmcube
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/build.make:406: recipe for target 'ijkmcube' 
failed
make[2]: *** [ijkmcube] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:131: recipe for target ' 
CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone help? Thank you

**Edit 2**

```
PROJECT(IJKMCUBE)

#---------------------------------------------------------

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

IF (NOT DEFINED ${IJK_DIR})
 GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(IJK_ABSOLUTE_PATH "../.." ABSOLUTE)
 SET(IJK_DIR ${IJK_ABSOLUTE_PATH} CACHE PATH "IJK directory")
ENDIF (NOT DEFINED ${IJK_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${IJK_DIR}/")
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${IJK_DIR}/lib CACHE PATH "Library directory")
SET(IJKMCUBE_DIR "src/ijkmcube")
SET(NRRD_LIBDIR "${IJK_DIR}/lib")
SET(IJK_ISOTABLE_DIR "${IJK_DIR}/isotable" CACHE PATH "Isotable 
 directory")

#---------------------------------------------------------

IF (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
 SET (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING 
   "Default build type: Release" FORCE)
ENDIF (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${IJK_DIR}/include")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("${NRRD_LIBDIR}")
LINK_LIBRARIES(expat NrrdIO z)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DIJK_ISOTABLE_DIR=\"${IJK_ISOTABLE_DIR}\")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(ijkmcube ijkmcube_main.cxx ijkmcubeIO.cxx ijkmcube.cxx 
                    ijkmcube_datastruct.cxx ijkmcube_sub.cxx 
                    ijkmcube_extract.cxx ijkmcube_util.cxx 
                    ijksnapmc.cxx 
                    ijktable.cxx ijktable_poly.cxx ijktable_ambig.cxx
                    ijkoctree.cxx ijkxitIO.cxx)

 ADD_LIBRARY(ijkmcubeL STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ijkmcubeIO.cxx 
             ijkmcube.cxx ijkmcube_datastruct.cxx ijkmcube_sub.cxx 
             ijkmcube_extract.cxx ijkmcube_util.cxx ijksnapmc.cxx 
             ijktable.cxx ijkoctree.cxx ijkxitIO.cxx)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(ijkmcubeL PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ijkmcube)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(lib DEPENDS ijkmcubeL)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${IJK_DIR})
INSTALL(TARGETS ijkmcube DESTINATION "bin/linux")

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(tar WORKING_DIRECTORY ../.. COMMAND tar cvfh 
${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/ijkmcube.tar ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/README 
${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/INSTALL ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/RELEASE_NOTES 
${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.cxx ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.h ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.txx 
${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/man/* 
${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/ijkmcube_doxygen.config)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(doc COMMAND doxygen ijkmcube_doxygen.config)
```

**SOLVED**

Tsyvarev solved it, the libNrrdIO.a file has to be copied to /usr/lib/. Refer to comments for the exact solution

Comment: The error is about inability of `ld` to find your `NrrdIO` library. What is an **absolute path** to that library? (You need to have this library **installed**, so the library file like `NrrdIO.a` should appear).

Comment: Yes, I'm getting lNrrdIO.a and linking it using sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/lNrrdIO.a ld.     But then I'm getting the second error.

Comment: `ld` is a **linker**, and `NrrdIO.a` is a **library**. No sence to make one of them to be a link to another. What is the *original* place of `NrrdIO.a` file?

Comment: The original place of the `NrrdIo.a` file is in my Downloads folder, where I ran `ccmake .`, `cmake .`, `make` and `make install`.  I was trying to make ld point to NrrdIO.a, after copying it into /usr/bin/. It shouldn't be that way?

Comment: Directory `/usr/bin` contains **executable** files, not *libraries*. Among standard directories for libraries there is, e.g., `/usr/lib` one.

Comment: I made ld point to the location where lNrrdIO.a  is created, using `sudo ln -sfn /home/subham/Downloads/NrrdIO-1.9.0-src/lNrrdIO.a ld` but still got the second error

Comment: "I made ld point to the location where lNrrdIO.a is created" - By making a link named `ld` you are **removing the linker** (`ld`). Without the linker you definitely cannot build any library. What you need is to make a link named `lNrrdIO.a`, so it will point to actuall library location: `sudo ln -sfn /home/subham/Downloads/NrrdIO-1.9.0-src/lNrrdIO.a lNrrdIO.a` (run this command from `/usr/lib` directory). And restore original `/usr/bin/ld` file.

Comment: I tried what you said, it should have worked, but I am getting the same error. For some reason it is looking for NrrdIO in `usr/bin/ld`, instead of `usr/bin`.

Comment: In the first error log, the line `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNrrdIO` means that **linker**, which absolute path is `/usr/bin/ld`, looks for `NrrdIO` library, and cannot find it. That line says **nothing** about where the library is searched.

Comment: In the second error log, the line `collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'` means that **linker** itself, as an executable named `ld`, cannot be found. That log says nothing about the library, because it is linker who should search the library, but the linker is absent.

Comment: I did what you said, and checked as follows:  `file lNrrdIO` gives 
`lNrrdIO: symbolic link to /home/subham/Downloads/NrrdIO-1.9.0-src/lNrrdIO.a` and `file lNrrdIO.a` gives
`lNrrdIO.a: symbolic link to /home/subham/Downloads/NrrdIO-1.9.0-src/lNrrdIO.a`   I ran both of them in `/usr/bin`

Comment: How do I make ld look for NrrdIO? I thought I would have to link it directly to NrrdIO using sfn, I did that, which was wrong. `lNrrdIO.a` and `lNrrdIO` are present in `usr/bin`, have to find a way to link these 2? I am not sure if it helps, but `file ld` points to `ld: symbolic link to x86_64-linux-gnu-ld`

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: The 1st error only, ld is linking to another link, when I run `file ld`, I get:   `ld: symbolic link to x86_64-linux-gnu-ld`. How do I make it search for lNrrdIO?

Comment: You have created a link to `lNrrdIO.a` under `/usr/lib` (not `/usr/bin` !), don't you?

Comment: You are right! I was making a mistake here, creating it under `usr/bin` , not under `usr/lib`. Sorry for being careless and wasting your time. There is an issue with lNrrdIO as well, I used libNrrdIO.a from NrrdIO v 1.11.0, modified the Cmakelists, and copied it into /usr/lib. Now its able to compile without any errors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On Stack Overflow we write "Solved" neither in the title nor in the question post. Having an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) adds a green indicator, which means that the original problem has been solved. Also, on Stack Overflow the asker is able to create its own answer, which can be accepted too. See [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) help topic about more info.

Comment: How do I mark it as the correct answer? I can't move it to chat

Comment: For mark correct answer the answer should exist. Our current discussion is in *comments*, they are not treated as **answers**. You may write an **answer** by filling "Your Answer" edit box and pressing "Post Your Answer" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given by @Tsyvarev:

By making a link named `ld` you are removing the original linker (ld). Without the linker you definitely cannot build any library. What you need is to make a link named `lNrrdIO.a`, so it will point to the actual library location: `sudo ln -sfn /home/subham/Downloads/NrrdIO-1.9.0-src/lNrrdIO.a lNrrdIO.a` (run this command from `/usr/lib` directory). And restore original `/usr/bin/ld` file.