# Cannot find libNrrdIO link library

Tags: makefile, cmake, symlink

This question is an extension of the following:

[Cannot find a link library (lNrrdIO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999339/cannot-find-a-link-library-lnrrdio/55138643#55138643)

The solution given by Tsyvarev worked for `lNrrdIO.a`, compiled from NrrdIO version 1.9.0, but when i tried the same thing from NrrdIO version 1.11.0, which generates a library `libNrrdIO.a`. I did exactly the same things for both, just modifying the cmakelists.txt in the `LINK_LIBRARIES` line, by changing `NrrdIO` to `ibNrrdIO`. Bu this is giving the following error:

```
[  7%] Linking CXX executable ijkmcube
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libNrrdIO
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/build.make:406: recipe for target 'ijkmcube' 
failed
make[2]: *** [ijkmcube] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:131: recipe for target 
'CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ijkmcube.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
PROJECT(IJKMCUBE)    

#---------------------------------------------------------    

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)    

IF (NOT DEFINED ${IJK_DIR})
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(IJK_ABSOLUTE_PATH "../.." ABSOLUTE)
  SET(IJK_DIR ${IJK_ABSOLUTE_PATH} CACHE PATH "IJK directory")
ENDIF (NOT DEFINED ${IJK_DIR})    

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${IJK_DIR}/")
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${IJK_DIR}/lib CACHE PATH "Library directory")
SET(IJKMCUBE_DIR "src/ijkmcube")
SET(NRRD_LIBDIR "${IJK_DIR}/lib")
SET(IJK_ISOTABLE_DIR "${IJK_DIR}/isotable" CACHE PATH "Isotable directory")    

#---------------------------------------------------------    

IF (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING 
       "Default build type: Release" FORCE)
ENDIF (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)    

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${IJK_DIR}/include")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("${NRRD_LIBDIR}")
LINK_LIBRARIES(expat ibNrrdIO z)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DIJK_ISOTABLE_DIR=\"${IJK_ISOTABLE_DIR}\")    

ADD_EXECUTABLE(ijkmcube ijkmcube_main.cxx ijkmcubeIO.cxx ijkmcube.cxx 
                        ijkmcube_datastruct.cxx ijkmcube_sub.cxx 
                        ijkmcube_extract.cxx ijkmcube_util.cxx ijksnapmc.cxx 
                        ijktable.cxx ijktable_poly.cxx ijktable_ambig.cxx
                        ijkoctree.cxx ijkxitIO.cxx)    

ADD_LIBRARY(ijkmcubeL STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ijkmcubeIO.cxx ijkmcube.cxx ijkmcube_datastruct.cxx ijkmcube_sub.cxx ijkmcube_extract.cxx ijkmcube_util.cxx ijksnapmc.cxx ijktable.cxx ijkoctree.cxx ijkxitIO.cxx)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(ijkmcubeL PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ijkmcube)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(lib DEPENDS ijkmcubeL)    

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${IJK_DIR})
INSTALL(TARGETS ijkmcube DESTINATION "bin/linux")    

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(tar WORKING_DIRECTORY ../.. COMMAND tar cvfh ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/ijkmcube.tar ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/README ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/INSTALL ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/RELEASE_NOTES ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.cxx ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.h ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/*.txx ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/man/* ${IJKMCUBE_DIR}/ijkmcube_doxygen.config)    

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(doc COMMAND doxygen ijkmcube_doxygen.config)
```

Can someone help identify what the problem could be? Is it possible to make cmake search for the library `libNrrdIO.a`? using some in-built function?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to link with the library `libNrrdIO.a`, why do you **omit** the first letter in its name (`ibNrrdIO`)? In the error message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libNrrdIO` part `-l` is a **linker option** (which causes the linker to link with the library), it is not a part of the library name. BTW, the code you provide still uses `NrrdIO` in `LINK_LIBRARIES` call...

Comment: I was omitting the first letter because I thought it was joining l to `ibNrrdIO`, when I tried with libNrrdIO, the error changed to `cannot find -llibNrrdIO` . Sorry didn't put the updated makelist file, I'll change it. When I ran it with `NrrdIO`, I got the error `cannot find -lNrrdIO`, so I thought it is appending l on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally resolved, with the help of Dr. Wenger from the Ohio State University, he suggested making 2 modifications to the CMakeLists of NrrdIO version 1.11.0, by setting the `QNANHABIT` value to 1 and uncommenting the line `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_ZLIB=1)` I've attached the modified CMakeLists file for reference:

```
# NrrdIO: stand-alone code for basic nrrd functionality
# Copyright (C) 2011, 2010, 2009  University of Chicago
# Copyright (C) 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005  Gordon Kindlmann
# Copyright (C) 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998  University of Utah
#
# This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
# warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any
# damages arising from the use of this software.
# 
# Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any
# purpose, including commercial applications, and to alter it and
# redistribute it freely, subject to the following restrictions:
# 
# 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must
#    not claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this
#    software in a product, an acknowledgment in the product
#    documentation would be appreciated but is not required.
#
#   2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must
#    not be misrepresented as being the original software.
# 
# 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
#    

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.4)
PROJECT(NrrdIO)
INCLUDE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION("^.*.h$")    

#
# This CMake file configures the NrrdIO library build.  NrrdIO
# is used by Insight/Code/IO/itkNrrdIO for reading/writing 
# "Nearly Raw Raster Data" within the open-source Teem software 
# package. See http://teem.sourceforge.net for more information.
#    

SET(nrrdio_SRCS comment.c enumsNrrd.c mop.c string.c 754.c defaultsNrrd.c
parseAir.c dio.c format.c parseNrrd.c formatEPS.c encoding.c
formatNRRD.c encodingAscii.c formatPNG.c encodingBzip2.c
formatPNM.c accessors.c encodingGzip.c formatText.c 
array.c encodingHex.c formatVTK.c read.c arraysNrrd.c encodingRaw.c 
gzio.c reorder.c write.c axis.c endianAir.c  keyvalue.c
biffbiff.c biffmsg.c endianNrrd.c methodsNrrd.c  sane.c enum.c
miscAir.c simple.c )    

# Turn on TEEM_BUILD so that the proper dll export def's are 
# used on windows builds.
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_BUILD=1)    

#The QNANHIBIT variable is configured by the root level CMakeLists.txt
IF(QNANHIBIT)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_QNANHIBIT=1)
ELSE(QNANHIBIT)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_QNANHIBIT=1)
ENDIF(QNANHIBIT)    

#DirectIO is the fast way to do multi-gigabyte I/O and currently only available
#for SGI platforms.  Use of DirectIO is enabled manually for now.
#OPTION(USE_DIRECTIO "Use DirectIO for Nrrd file IO.  Only valid on SGI systems." 0)
#MARK_AS_ADVANCED(USE_DIRECTIO)
#IF(USE_DIRECTIO)
#  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_DIO=1)
#ELSE(USE_DIRECTIO)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_DIO=0)
#ENDIF(USE_DIRECTIO)    

# Possibly turn on usage of zlib compression (requires linking with libz)
# (i.e., programs compiled with ITKNrrdIO must also be compiled with zlib)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DTEEM_ZLIB=1)    

ADD_LIBRARY(NrrdIO ${nrrdio_SRCS} )    

## These are ITK-specific
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(NrrdIO ${ITK_ZLIB_LIBRARIES} )
#INSTALL_TARGETS(/lib/InsightToolkit ITKNrrdIO)
#INSTALL_FILES(/include/InsightToolkit/Utilities/NrrdIO "(\\.h)$")
```